# Why did the members of the Local Churches not mention the name of Witness Lee in their prayers when he was on his deathbed?

Tags: prayer, local-churches

When Witness Lee was terminally ill, all the members of the Local Churches (also known as Recovery) around the globe were asked to pray for him, yet without mentioning his name in their prayers. Why was it so? Is there any specific reason in Christianity as to why names of those who Christians pray for must not be mentioned in prayers?

Comment: Witness Lee was heavily influenced by [Watchman Nee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchman_Nee) who, in turn, was heavily influenced by the early (Darby and Kelly) [Plymouth Brethren](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plymouth_Brethren) who are famous for referring to one another by initials ('JND' and 'WK') rather  than by their full names. Perhaps the underlying reason for this (and for that stated by the OP) may be a desire to not overtly refer to a _person_ , rather than to a 'ministry', which ministry has been specifically sent by the Lord Jesus Christ to the whole Church.

Comment: @NigelJ - The prayers were not for the healing of the ministry, but specifically for the healing of Witness Lee. The phrase "Lord, heal our brother" was considered to be okay and absolutely acceptable, but not "Lord, heal brother Lee" or "Lord, heal Witness Lee".